# Pass variable to AWK command

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a `AWK` command and i want to use it in bash script. I want to give to `AWK` a big text file as variable.

I have tried:

1. `cat $var | awk 'regex'`
2. `echo $var | awk 'regex'`
3. `awk 'regex' <<< $var`

All three form does not work. When i try these command in shell `awk 'regex' file` it works.
How can i pass a variable as Input to AWK command,i dont want to pass file to `AWK`. Is that possible or not.

Comment: Barmar and Abybhava are right.
If you give more clarity on question and expected output we can help you further

Comment: "I want to give to AWK a big text file as variable"... What does `var` contain? file name, or file data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, this should also work:

```
awk 'regex' <<< "$var"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the variable to prevent newlines from being converted to spaces:

```
echo "$var" | awk 'regex'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$ awk -v awkvar="$var" 'BEGIN{if (awkvar ~ "foobar"){print var}}'
foobar
```

Comment: Where is the regex matching that was in his original script?

Comment: Post fixed, using regex now

Comment: That will treat the variable as just one line, instead of processing it line by line.